# What is the formula for the collision of two "stretched spheres"?

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, geometry

In Smash Bros Melee, hitboxes aren't perfect spheres or boxes. They are, instead, a shape that looks like a continuous line of consecutive spheres:

[image]

[image]

I.e., the geometry can represented as:

```
Hitbox : (fromPos : V3, fromRad : V3, toPos : V3, toRad : V3)
```

Of course, one could emulate that by creating several spheres in a row, but it will probably not be the most efficient solution. So, what is a formula to test the collision of two of those hitboxes?

Comment: http://thunderfist-podium.blogspot.ca/2012/02/capsule-capsule-collision-in-games.html

Comment: It's called a capsule. From a collision detection perspective, this is made up of three shapes - 2 spheres and a cylinder that extends between them. You would need to perform collision detection / resolution against each of those, TMK. The spheres are easy, since they never need to be transformed to another orientation, but the cylinder is a little trickier as it does need to be oriented as the character moves, using matrix multiplications. Or just use a 3D physics library?